# NotificationHub send notification in registered tag UWP

Tags: c#, azure, win-universal-app, azure-notificationhub

Is there a way to send a notification with UWP app through NotificationHub? In many tutorials they send notifications with a  C# console application using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs Nuget package. I cannot install this package in a UWP app.
Can i specifically send a notification to a tagged device that i register with RegisterNativeAsync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The code is like @Kyle but i had to add

```
request.Headers.Add("X-WNS-Type", "wns/toast");
```

in order to send a push notification

M[ore details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465435.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Per my experience, I think the simple way for sending notification in a UWP app is to using Notification Hub REST APIs via HttpClient, without the issues for platform compatibility.

Please refer to the document [Notification Hubs REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223264.aspx).

You can try to refer to the doc [`Using REST APIs from a Backend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495628.aspx) to make your UWP app as a backend to send messages. For example, [Send a WNS Native Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223272.aspx).

Hope it helps.

Comment: That helped a lot. I am trying now to send a notification with `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpClient` but i get a 500 Internal Server error. Do you have any idea why that happens? I am using [this authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495627.aspx)

Comment: @Jerrak0s Could you share your code for helping analysis the issue?

Comment: `using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
             {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,uri);
                request.Content = new StringContent(toast);
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization",getSaSToken(URL,1000));
                request.Headers.Add("ServiceBusNotification-Tags","TAG");
                request.Headers.Add("ServiceBusNotification-Format","windows");

                
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }`

Comment: `var toast = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">Hello</text></binding></visual></toast>";       
    var uri = "https://NAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net/NAME/messages/?api-version=2015-04";`

Comment: @Jerrak0s The value of the `Authorization` header is "`SharedAccessSignature <sas-token>`", please see the section `Create SAS Security Token` of the doc [`Common Concepts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495627.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code that sends a notification from a UWP through an Azure Notification Hub (However, it uses GCM instead of WNS, see how to change the code in the approved answer). It obviously needs a few changes like your hub's name, see the comments in the code for more info.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;


namespace SendNotification
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.sendNotification();
        }

        string Endpoint = "";
        string SasKeyName = "";
        string SasKeyValue = "";

        public void ConnectionStringUtility(string connectionString)
        {
            //Parse Connectionstring
            char[] separator = { ';' };
            string[] parts = connectionString.Split(separator);
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
            {
                if (parts[i].StartsWith("Endpoint"))
                    Endpoint = "https" + parts[i].Substring(11);
                if (parts[i].StartsWith("SharedAccessKeyName"))
                    SasKeyName = parts[i].Substring(20);
                if (parts[i].StartsWith("SharedAccessKey"))
                    SasKeyValue = parts[i].Substring(16);
            }
        }


        public string getSaSToken(string uri, int minUntilExpire)
        {
            string targetUri = Uri.EscapeDataString(uri.ToLower()).ToLower();

            // Add an expiration in seconds to it.
            long expiresOnDate = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
            expiresOnDate += minUntilExpire * 60 * 1000;
            long expires_seconds = expiresOnDate / 1000;
            String toSign = targetUri + "\n" + expires_seconds;

            // Generate a HMAC-SHA256 hash or the uri and expiration using your secret key.
            MacAlgorithmProvider macAlgorithmProvider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha256);
            BinaryStringEncoding encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;
            var messageBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(toSign, encoding);
            IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(SasKeyValue, encoding);
            CryptographicKey hmacKey = macAlgorithmProvider.CreateKey(keyBuffer);
            IBuffer signedMessage = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, messageBuffer);

            string signature = Uri.EscapeDataString(CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signedMessage));

            return "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + targetUri + "&sig=" + signature + "&se=" + expires_seconds + "&skn=" + SasKeyName;
        }


        public async void sendNotification()
        {
            ConnectionStringUtility("YOURHubFullAccess"); //insert your HubFullAccess here (a string that can be copied from the Azure Portal by clicking Access Policies on the Settings blade for your notification hub)

            //replace YOURHUBNAME with whatever you named your notification hub in azure 
            var uri = Endpoint + "YOURHUBNAME" + "/messages/?api-version=2015-01";
            string json = "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"" + "Hello World!" + "\"}}";


            //send an HTTP POST request
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
                request.Content = new StringContent(json);

                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", getSaSToken(uri, 1000));
                request.Headers.Add("ServiceBusNotification-Format", "gcm");
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work for you? I get a 400 bad request error

Comment: @Jerrak0s yes it does, I have tested it multiple times, even on different computers. Double check your HubFullAccess string, and your hub's name and make sure you enter them in the right place within the code. Also make sure that you've configured your hub correctly, I personally used this guide to configure it: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-get-started/
If you have any further questions let me know and i'll try to help you as much as I can.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed? Just tried it with the W10 UWP.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/

Comment: Yes of course but i cannot find an example of sending a notification. Only receiving with NotificationHub class.