# UWP push notifications

Tags: c#, php, azure, push-notification, uwp

This is for an application for windows 10.
I followed this tutorial:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview

At this point I got the next values right:

> **SID**
>
> **Secret**
>
> **Uri(I got this on my application)**

The Uri I got is with this simple code:

> `channel=await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();`

With the line above I got a URL that is going to be useful for about a month.

The part that is now not posible for me to do is send the Push notification to the App.

Any light on how to use the Uri and how to send the information to it I will be glad, because I the 400 error, that is about something wrong with my post message.

This link show how to send the information, but I don't get any useful code.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465435

**Also**:

I don't own or use any cloud based web service.

Can I get push notifications on release or debug mode?

Can the push notification with the correct Uri be done with PHP?

Comment: This question is really helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601278/notificationhub-send-notification-in-registered-tag-uwp

Comment: This question actually helped me. This [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification/) was especially useful, but it has some bugs on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just completing the solution from Jerrak0s

Given your Azure notification Hub:
[image]

The code to send Push Notification using REST:

```
private static async void SendNotificationAsync()
{
        //Setting\Access policies\DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature policy
        string connStr = "Endpoint=sb://[namespace].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=xyz";
        var util = new ConnectionStringUtility(connStr);

        //toast in XML
        var toast = "<toast>    <visual>
                       <binding template="ToastText01">
                         < text id = "1" > Test message </ text >
                     </ binding >    </ visual > </ toast >";

        //call WNS
        var uri = "https://[namespace].servicebus.windows.net/[hub name]/messages/?api-version=2015-04";

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {                
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
            request.Content = new StringContent(toast);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", util.getSaSToken(uri, 1000));
            //request.Headers.Add("ServiceBusNotification-Tags", "TAG");
            request.Headers.Add("ServiceBusNotification-Format", "windows");
            request.Headers.Add("X-WNS-Type", "wns/toast");
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

The Utility class for parsing the endpoint and SAS token from:

```
public class ConnectionStringUtility
{
    public string Endpoint { get; private set; }
    public string SasKeyName { get; private set; }
    public string SasKeyValue { get; private set; }

    public ConnectionStringUtility(string connectionString)
    {
        //Parse Connectionstring
        char[] separator = { ';' };
        string[] parts = connectionString.Split(separator);
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (parts[i].StartsWith("Endpoint"))
                Endpoint = "https" + parts[i].Substring(11);
            if (parts[i].StartsWith("SharedAccessKeyName"))
                SasKeyName = parts[i].Substring(20);
            if (parts[i].StartsWith("SharedAccessKey"))
                SasKeyValue = parts[i].Substring(16);
        }
    }

    public string getSaSToken(string uri, int minUntilExpire)
    {
        string targetUri = Uri.EscapeDataString(uri.ToLower()).ToLower();

        // Add an expiration in seconds to it.
        long expiresOnDate = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        expiresOnDate += minUntilExpire * 60 * 1000;
        long expires_seconds = expiresOnDate / 1000;
        String toSign = targetUri + "\n" + expires_seconds;

        // Generate a HMAC-SHA256 hash or the uri and expiration using your secret key.
        MacAlgorithmProvider macAlgorithmProvider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha256);
        BinaryStringEncoding encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;
        var messageBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(toSign, encoding);
        IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(SasKeyValue, encoding);
        CryptographicKey hmacKey = macAlgorithmProvider.CreateKey(keyBuffer);
        IBuffer signedMessage = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, messageBuffer);

        string signature = Uri.EscapeDataString(CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signedMessage));

        return "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + targetUri + "&sig=" + signature + "&se=" + expires_seconds + "&skn=" + SasKeyName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this, it seems useful.